# laying out formitems in flex

Tags: apache-flex, layout, textbox, mxml

for some reason my code is not having the desired effect of having labels to the left of the textinput fields*(like in nearly all normal scenarios with forms). The labels are appearing above the textinput fields. I would also like to make some of them read only. Any advice much appreciated

Basically what i have is text sitting above the textbox instead of alongside it to the left.

Here is my code:

```
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
 <mx:HBox>
 <mx:FormItem textAlign="left" <mx:Label text="TEST"  textAlign="left"                 fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold"/>    
 <mx:TextInput  enabled="true" textAlign="right"/> </mx:FormItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the label field of the formitem.

```
<mx:FormItem textAlign="left" label="TEST" fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold"/>    
    <mx:TextInput  enabled="true" textAlign="right">
</mx:FormItem>
```

If you want read-only, then you can put `editable="true|false"` in the `TextInput`.

Comment: thanks jacob, but im not sure this works. did you check this? is there a way of viewing flex code online to see what the visual components look like?